# leaked ServiceConnection that was originally bound here

Tags: java, android

I open an app do something and somehow the app crashes. I open it again and get this error. I want to know the reason and solution for this error. Can anyone please help.

```
   15 01:25:59.698  31122-31122/com.myApp.myApp E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity com.myApp.myApp.Main has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.common.a@412XXfa8 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.myApp.myApp.Main has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.common.a@412XXfa8 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1470)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1459)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.h(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.invokeMethodQuietly(Utility.java:899)
            at com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers.getAndroidId(AttributionIdentifiers.java:85)
            at com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers.getAttributionIdentifiers(AttributionIdentifiers.java:110)
            at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.getSessionEventsState(AppEventsLogger.java:751)
            at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.access$600(AppEventsLogger.java:127)
            at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger$5.run(AppEventsLogger.java:708)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: You found a solution?

Comment: Hello @Maven, did you find out solution?

Answer (score 2):

unBind your service connection at onStop() or onDestroy()

```
unBindService(connection);
```